# Question About How Qiskit Reset Gate Affects Other Entangled Qubits

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, measurement

I am trying to understand how the reset gate in Qiskit affects qubits its entangled with. Consider the following circuit with qubits $q_0$ and $q_1$:

[image]

Where circuit240 takes $|0\rangle$ to $a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$ and circuit 244 takes $|0\rangle$ to $c|0\rangle + d|1\rangle$. Right before the reset gate on qubit $q_1$ the state of this circuit is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c|1\rangle + d|0\rangle)|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a|1\rangle + b|0\rangle)|1\rangle \tag{1}$$

I'm not quite sure how to mathematically represent what this quantum reset gate does to the quantum entangled state. For example, I tried a few tests with this circuit where I played with the values $a$ and $c$ and tested how the quantum reset gate affects the measurement of the qubit $q_0$. It seems that whether or not the quantum reset gate is added, it doesn't affect the measurements of the other entangled qubit. Does this generally hold?

Furthermore, when I take the qubit expression above and just reset qubit $q_1$to $|0\rangle$ I get the following:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c|1\rangle + d|0\rangle)|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a|1\rangle + b|0\rangle)|0\rangle \tag{2}$$

$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}((a + c)|1\rangle + (b + d)|0\rangle)|0\rangle \tag{3}$$

But, mathematically, the probability of measuring $q_0$ as $|0\rangle$ in $(3)$ is not the same as the probability in  qubit expression $(1)$(even though the tests show that removing the reset gate did not change the probability of measuring a $|0\rangle$ in the qubit $q_0$. What is the correct way to represent what the qubit reset gate does to an entangled qubit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reset gate is equivalent to a swap gate between the target qubit and a new ancilla qubit in the $|0\rangle$ state. So you can replace your question with "how does swapping a qubit Q with an fresh ancilla qubit affect the qubits Q is entangled with?" or "how does discarding Q affect the qubits Q is entangled with". And the answer is that, for all intents and purposes, it doesn't affect them at all.

There is no test you can do on the qubits entangled with Q that can determined whether or not Q was discarded, or whether or not Q was swapped for a fresh ancilla qubit. Therefore there is no test you can do on the qubits entangled with Q (that don't involve measuring Q's value) whose outcome depends on whether or not Q was reset.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the answer. However, this means that if I want to uncompute/reverse a circuit with a reset gate I would need to compute the value of the qubit before resetting and then swap that in when uncomputing, correct?

Comment: @RehaanAhmad You can't use a reset gate to uncompute anything, and if you uncompute something you don't need the reset gate (because the qubit will be in the zero state already).

Comment: Perhaps I misphrased the comment above. Lets say I have a circuit that takes $|v\rangle$ to $U|v\rangle$ where U is a circuit that has some reset gates. Now, I want to make another circuit $U^{\dagger}$, that takes $U|v\rangle$ to $|v\rangle$. In this case, how could I construct the circuit $U^{\dagger}$? I would need to know the value of each of the qubits before they were initially reset in order to do so right?

Comment: Typically you'd implement a $U^\dagger$ that would work for any value, not just one.

Comment: Right, which means that reversing a circuit with the reset gate isn't a straightforward task, correct (as opposed to reversing other more standard gates)? Let's say I have a circuit that is just the reset gate, taking any $|v\rangle$  to $|0\rangle$. There is no easy way to uncompute this circuit, right? (other than having a copy of $|v\rangle$ to begin with and using it)

Comment: @RehaanAhmad When you reverse a circuit with a reset gate, the reversed reset gate becomes an implicit promise that the qubit will be zero at that point. You can measure the qubit to verify, and if you ever see (1) then the circuit was used incorrectly (e.g. applying it to a state that didn't come out of the forward circuit, i.e. you didn't satisfy possible_outputs(forward) == allowed_inputs(backward) ).

Comment: @CraigGidney I would love your expertise on [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32798).

Answer (score 2):

'Internally, these reset instructions are composed of a mid-circuit measurement followed by an x-gate conditioned on the outcome of the measurement.'

As I understand it, the reset will collapse the qubit to either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ because of the measurement. Due to the superposition this will also collapse the qubit entangled with the reset qubit

source: 
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2021/02/quantum-mid-circuit-measurement/