# Re-initializing qubits in a circuit without losing superposition

Tags: programming, qiskit

So recently I was building some circuit made of subcircuits. My subcircuits happen to use auxiliary qubits, that are always initialized in the state $|0\rangle$ and are not used after the calculation. Hence, I wanted to use the same set of auxiliary qubits for all the subcircuits by reinitializing them between subcircuits. As I code on Qiskit, I used reset gates to do so.

But I have a problem : my circuit is correct on each possible input state that belongs to the basis $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}^{\otimes n}$, but the reset gates make it fail for any superposed state, henceforth losing all quantum advantage.

I'll explain the problem with a simplified example : let's say that I have two subcircuits, C and C', that operate on 1 main qubit (that I want to change) and use 1 auxiliary qubit. When C takes as input $|0\rangle$ for the main qubit, it outputs the main qubit in the state $|0\rangle$ and leaves the auxiliary qubits in the state $|0\rangle$, and when it takes as input $|1\rangle$ for the main qubit, it outputs the main qubit in the state $|1\rangle$ and gets the auxiliary qubits in the state $|1\rangle$. My full circuit resets the auxiliary gate between C and C' (with the Qiskit reset gate) and then C' is applied to get the wanted output on the main qubit. Now, if I input the state $\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ on the main qubit, which is overall (taking into account the auxiliary qubit) the input state $\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \otimes |0\rangle$, after C we get :
$$\frac{|00\rangle+|11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$
But then after the reset gate we don't get :
$$\frac{|00\rangle+|10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$
But $|00\rangle$ 50% of the time and $|10\rangle$ 50% of the time. As superposition is broken, the main circuit gets flawed.

This behavior can be reproduced with the following code:

```
qc=QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.reset(1)
backend=Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
plot_histogram(execute(qc,backend,shots=1024).result().get_counts())
```

And by the way, in my understanding, this is in disagreement with this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12823/14793) - which motivated me to ask my question, even if it may seem redundant at first sight.

Is there a way I could fix that ?

I am pessimistic, as in my previous example, the operation I'd like to apply isn't unitary. But I know that I can find on this site people that are amazing at quantum computing, so I have hope that a solution can be found.

Thanks a lot,

Thomas

Comment: Hi Thomas! I can't reproduce your issue, if I'm running your code above I'm getting 50% $|00\rangle$ and 50% $|10\rangle$. Can you try installing the latest version of Qiskit and see if the behavior persists?

Comment: Hello Cryoris ! Well we then have the same behavior running this code :) And here is my problem, because I wanted to keep the superposition, and it is lost. My problem isn't a bug in Qiskit, it is that what I used to perform my resetting qubits action didn't go as I wanted. I am not saying that Qiskit reset gates behave wrongly, I'm saying that they do not fit my needs, as explained in the example. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important point to understand is that you lose the superposition and obtain a *classical mixture* of states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ on the first qubit.
If you look at the circuit diagram below:

- Before applying the reset you're in a Bell state (green).
- As you apply the reset, you effectively remove the qubit from the system, you can think of it as tracing it out. If you trace out system B in the Bell state you obtain a maximally mixed state (blue).
- Finally, you add a new qubit in state $|0\rangle$ that has no correlation whatsoever with qubit A, so you end up in a product state of a mixed state and the zero state (red).

[image]

This means your final state is **not** a pure state where the first qubit is in state $\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{2}$ and the second one, reset, in state $|0\rangle$. Instead, it is a mix of **classical probabilities**
$$
\rho_{AB} = (p_1 \rho_1 + p_2 \rho_2) \otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|
$$
where $p_1 = p_2 = 1/2$ and
$$
\rho_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, 
\rho_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

If you now perform a statevector simulation of this circuit, you have a 50% probability of measuring state $|00\rangle$ and 50% of measuring $|10\rangle$. Running this in Qiskit

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.reset(1)

print(circuit.draw())

backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
statevector = execute(circuit, backend).result().get_statevector()
print('Statevector')
print(statevector)
```

will print `[1, 0, 0, 0]` in half the cases and `[0, 1, 0, 0]` in the other half. It is a classical combination of quantum states, not a superposition like `[0.707, 0.707, 0, 0]`.

What's a bit confusing now is that counting shots gives the same histogram for the classical mix of quantum states as for superposition. That's because the probability to measure either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ is the same for both.
In Qiskit code:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.reset(1)
circuit.measure_all() 

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
counts = execute(circuit, backend).result().get_counts()
print('Counts')
print(counts)
```

Will give on average `{'00': 512, '10': 512}`.
But the pure state $|\phi\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{2} \otimes |0\rangle$ will give the same histogram:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.measure_all()
```

A reset is a very "brutal" non-unitary operation and will destroy the pure state you have.

---

Note: you can derive the same result by computing the density matrices in the circuit from @Egretta.Thula, I just skipped it to make the diagram easier.

Comment: Overall, your answer makes sense to me, but there's something I don't really understand.
You said $\mathbb{1}_2/2 \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 |_B$ to be a state, and I don't follow you on that. From what I know of quantum mechanics (I'm still a grad student, so maybe it's incomplete), you are taking the tensor product of two operators, and thus you get an operator and not a state. 
As a result, I don't know whether your answer proves that in a general manner, there is no way I can reset my qubits as I initially wanted.
Could you please clarify that ?
Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: This is a density matrix representation (in fact all $\rho$ I used are) of a quantum state. A density matrix can represent more general states, such as _mixed_ states, while the "ket"/vector representation only works for _pure_ states. So $\mathbb{1}/2 \otimes |0\rangle\langle0|$ is a tensor product of two states (in density matrix representation), not operators. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix for more details on density matrices.

Comment: Ok, I think that I understand your answer now, thanks a lot. It definitely answers my question, thanks a lot for all the details you provided.

Comment: Sure thing, it was a good question!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this link](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/systems/reset/backend_reset), IBM does not implement Reset instruction as a swap gate between the target qubit and a new ancilla qubit in the $|0⟩$ state. It is implemented as a

> not-gate conditioned on the
> measurement outcome of the qubit

Which means your circuit is equivalent to the following circuit:

[image]

This should explain the results you have obtained.